# I dont understand this line of code (hexchar_to_int(str[i]) << 4) | hexchar_to_int(str[i+1])) . Can someone explains me

Tags: c++17

I reviewed these lines of codes which used to convert string to binary, but i cant understand what this 
line of code is doing (hexchar_to_int(str[i]) << 4) | hexchar_to_int(str[i+1]), i am frustrated 
with this bit manipulation here, 8 bit of unsigned int used and we shifted left to get the least 4
significant bits. But i don't know the purpose of doing so.

```
unsigned char hexchar_to_int(char const ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') return ch - '0';
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F') return ch - 'A' + 10;
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f') return ch - 'a' + 10;
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid hexadecimal character");
 }

 std::vector<unsigned char> hexstr_to_bytes(std::string_view str)
 {
     std::vector<unsigned char> result;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i += 2)
     {
          result.push_back((hexchar_to_int(str[i]) << 4) | hexchar_to_int(str[i+1]));
     }
     return result;

 }
```

Comment: <<4 is * 2^4 or *16, shifting LEFT. the | is a simple addition of the 2 hexa characters at their correct place. 0xab = 10*16+11=171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<4` is `*2^4` or `*16`, shifting *left*, not right.
The `|` is a simple addition of the 2 hexa characters at their correct place.
See 0xab = 10*16 + 11 = 171